# Website down for maintenance page on IIS for external visitors

Tags: asp.net, iis

I want to put up a website down for maintenance for "external" visitors while I do some major deployment on a website hosted in IIS. I have read about creating a "App_Offline.htm" page in the web root. Can I still browse the website under localhost (I will log into the server) while visitors browsing via domain names will get to see the "down for maintenance" page? I would like to do some testing before I make the changes available to the visitors.

Comment: Might I suggest that you ask this question at http://serverfault.com?  Stack Overflow is for programming questions.  This applies more to system administration.

Comment: I vote +1 as an idea, and because you can solve it with programming only.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved the issue in the following way:

1. I added a key called "MaintanenceMode" in web.config file

`<appSettings>
    <add key="MaintenanceMode" value="true" />
</appSettings>`

2. I added an action result and view in home controller

`public class HomeController : BaseController
{
    public ActionResult Offline()
    {
        return View("Offline");
    }
}`

3. I changed Global.asax.cs file check for the MaintenanceMode key and redirected all external requests (except for image, css and js file requests) to offline page

`protected void Application_BeginRequest()
{
    if (WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["MaintenanceMode"] == "true")
    {
        if (!Request.IsLocal && !Request.Path.Contains("bundles") && !Request.Path.Contains("Content"))
        {
            HttpContext.Current.RewritePath("/home/offline");
        }
    }
}`

Answer (score 4):

By default when you open the `app_offline.htm` the asp.net is stop that web pages from run.

But you can do it with some programming on global.asax as:

```
protected void Application_BeginRequest(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    HttpApplication app = (HttpApplication)sender;

    // if its not local - let see if we go offline
    if (!app.Request.IsLocal)
    {
        // the file we look now is the app_offline_alt.htm
        string cOffLineFile = HttpRuntime.AppDomainAppPath + "app_offline_alt.htm";

        // if exist on root
        if (System.IO.File.Exists(cOffLineFile))
        {
            using (var fp = System.IO.File.OpenText(cOffLineFile))
            {
                // read it and send it to the browser
                app.Response.Write(fp.ReadToEnd());
                fp.Close();
            }

            // and stop the rest of processing
            app.Response.End();
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Good answer. Do we have to read the file in a stream? Or we can simply do a response.redirect() or server.transfer() to the offline html file? If there a solution using URL Rewrite?

Comment: @TejSoft first of all I will appreciate if you vote and accept. Second, anything else than direct write cause problems, the server.transfer()/redirect will  probably crash at that point because you make an infinity loop.

Comment: this solution is the best so far.